# Azure Synapse - Run the same notebook parallelly from 2 pipelines

Tags: apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, concurrency, azure-synapse

I have the Azure Synapse Workspace and a *small* spark pool within it. I have written the code in such a way that the same spark notebook connecting to the same spark pool would be called multiple times based on the parameter that I pass from the Synapse pipeline.

Now the problem is two pipelines start at the same time but the notebook activity runs sequentially causing the second instance to be "queued" as shown below -

[image]

How can I make it parallel so my notebook starts at a time from  different pipelines?
More information -

Notebook code -

```
import logging
import findspark
findspark.init()
findspark.find()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from data_mesh_etl import table1, table2

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("MyApp") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:9.4.1.jre11,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-azure:3.3.1") \
    .getOrCreate()

spark.conf.set('spark.sql.caseSensitive', True)
spark.conf.set('spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields', 3000)

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

if p_table_name == 'table1':
    table1.load_table1_data_into_sql(spark, logger)

if p_table_name == 'table2':
    table2.load_table2_data_into_sql(spark, logger)
```

I pass the parameter `p_table_name` from `pipeline_table1` with the value as `table1` and from `pipeline_table2` with the value as `table2`
When these 2 pipelines start at a time, shouldn't my notebook also have 2 instances running in parallel? Is there any concurrency setting of Spark that I am missing here?

Can someone please help in this?

TIA!

Sanket Kelkar

Comment: you are calling synapse notebook inside ForEach?

Comment: No, it is just the "notebook" activity in both pipelines.

Comment: If it's the same spark pool, I think the Notebook will be in queued state only. are you using the same spark pool for both Notebooks?

Comment: yes, it is the same spark pool. The notebook is only one, it gets called from 2 pipelines and it uses the same spark pool.

Comment: So in this case, do I need 2 different spark pools? Like sparkPoolTable1 and sparkPoolTable2? How can set it up dynamically from my pipeline? Like these 2 tables, I have 15+ tables to load.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question here -
I got it working by simply increasing the size of the spark pool. See the attached screenshot where 4 spark job definitions were called at the same time, and they ran parallelly.

[image]

Note - In here I have tried the spark job definition but the same thing works on Notebooks as well.